# how to apply Fourier Transform on image using matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have a problem, which is how it is applied Fourier Transform (ftt) on the image (or how enhance image  used Fourier Transform)
when i run my program

- the input was fingerprint image
- the output was white image
- the problem is the output should be fingerprint image after enhance used Fourier Transform not white image

---

```
F=fft2( I );
factor=abs(F).^F;
block =ifft2(factor); 
R= fftshift(block);
```

I hope finding some help

Comment: What do you expect `abs(F).^F` to do?

Comment: F=fft2( I );
factor=abs(F).^F;
2 step to find Fourier Transform

Comment: You've already found the (discrete) Fourier transform, that's what `fft2` does.  I have no idea what `abs(F).^F` would achieve in practice.

Comment: Oli Charlesworth
first thanks for the help ,I try  Without ( abs(F).^F) but the result it is same .

Comment: If you do `F = fft2(I); block = ifft2(F);` then you should be back at the original image.

Comment: I still have the same problem,the output is white image 
I do not know Where is the problem in these steps
I=imread('101_1.tif');
 F=fft2( I);
 imshow(I)
 block =ifft2(F);
 imshow(block)

Answer (score 2):

The exponentiation of F.^F seems to be a big number, so it is above the upper value and matlab slice it to be the upper value.

```
% Calculating fft2
fft2im = fft2(double(im));
% Taking the spectrum with log scaling
fft2im = log(1+(abs(fft2im)));
% Putting DC in the middle:
spectrum = fftshift(fft2im);
% finding maximum in spectrum:
maximum = max(max(spectrum));
% scaling maximum to 255 and minimum to 0:
spectrum = 255*spectrum/maximum;
% Casting to uint8 to be able to display:
spectrum =  uint8(spectrum);
imshow(spectrum);
```

Comment: thanks but I still have the same problem
the output must be image after enhance used Fourier Transform

Comment: I will explain what I want from this enhancement I am working on project (how open door using fingerprint ), and i will design code using matlab to do this. the one of the steps in this project is per-processing the images of fingerprint , befor comparing image . It is one of the steps is to enhancement images 1 - histogram equalization 2 - Fourier transform The output must be the image of fingerprint after enhancement using Fourier transform not spectrum of the image .